# Bluetooth mouse problem

Tags: bluetooth

Hi I have installed a 'Blutooth Keyboard' and sucessfully paired it to my Pi B mod 3. But when I attach my 'Microsoft Designer Mouse' it pairs sucessfully but gives a message 'Connection failed - No usable services on this device' Any ideas on how to resolve this issue as the keyboard works fine.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi part of the Stack Exchange network, please consider using the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) link at the bottom of the page as that can give you guidance on how things _ought_ to work here.  Can you give us more details about the M$ Mouse, I'm going out on a limb here but I wonder whether those paragons of support for Open Software Systems 8-P are doing something non-standard.  Oh, and does this mouse work in other situations, and further more is it (still?) being _used_ by another system (i.e. one of those other situations)?

Comment: Product - Microsoft Designer Mouse from Amazon currently the latest model No 1679, Wireless platform  'Nordic nRF51822 (Bluetooth Low Energy)', Wireless frequency 2.4 GHz. Full product spec is on https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00S0CTU2Y/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1